# jbd2 causing high disk IO

Tags: ubuntu, raid, software-raid

A server I have has started getting sluggish lately, I checked iostat and disk was almost completely utilized even though the server is not running very much.

I've checked a few places and now pretty stumped where to look next. Any advice?

**iostat**

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00    65.00    0.00   58.00     0.00  1066.67    36.78     0.79   13.56    0.00   13.56  13.70  79.47
sdb               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md0               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md1               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md3               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md2               0.00     0.00    0.00  123.00     0.00  1065.33    17.32     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

**iotop**

```
282 be/3 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 90.05 % [jbd2/md2-8]
29257 be/4 rabbitmq    0.00 B/s  590.50 K/s  0.00 % 12.50 % beam.smp -W w -A 128 -P 1048576 -t 5000000 -stbt db -K true -B i -- -root /usr/lib/erlang -pr~q/mnesia/rabbit@feeds1" -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 25672 -kernel inet_dist_listen_max 25672
1184 be/4 influxdb    0.00 B/s   15.44 K/s  0.00 %  8.08 % influxd -pidfile /var/run/influxdb/influxd.pid -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
19203 be/4 root        0.00 B/s   39.35 M/s  0.00 %  0.29 % redis-rdb-bgsave 127.0.0.1:6379
 1180 be/4 influxdb    0.00 B/s   34.74 K/s  0.00 %  0.19 % influxd -pidfile /var/run/influxdb/influxd.pid -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
```

**mdstat**

```
root@feeds1 /home/lee # cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md2 : active raid1 sdb3[1](F) sda3[0]
  2684223488 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
  bitmap: 19/20 pages [76KB], 65536KB chunk

md3 : active raid1 sdb4[1](F) sda4[0]
  228477376 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
  bitmap: 2/2 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1](F) sda2[0]
  523712 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1](F) sda1[0]
  16760832 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: the server is not idle

Comment: Ok, rabbitmq and influxdb has a few queries every so often. Nothing crazy. What is running on here was running on a 1x core VPS and this is a dedicated server.